# How to display P tag contents in XHTML?

Tags: php, jquery, dom

Am actually getting confuse about my code...Well i have a file english.html which contains Ajax and JQuery which does some processing..The process works fine when the english.html file have .html extension, but when i change that extension to .xhtml it output nothing..

```
//english.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <title>Mobile View</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styless.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>                         
        function myPara() {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "dom.php",
                type: "GET",           
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(msg) {
                $("#para").html(msg);         
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
        }

    </script>   
</head>
<body id="home"  bgcolor="white "> 
<div class="wrapper">


    <div  id="para" style="width:auto; height:200px; overflow: auto;" >

        <script>myPara();</script>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html> 

Here is the code for dom.php
//dom.php
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
$xhtml = '<html>
<body>
<para>This is a paragraph</para>
<para>This is another paragraph</para>
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($xhtml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);


$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//para");
foreach ($elements as $node){
echo $node->nodeValue. "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging like checking your browser's javascsript console?

Comment: hmmmm i have other files like english.html with the same codes, and some of them works even with .xhtml extension ,but i don't know why the others are not working ??

how to set up the webserver to parse html files as php?

Comment: @MarcB Yes i did it,but there nothing apart the html content

Comment: Then what problem is preventing the result to be displayed??

Comment: If other pages work when you change the file extension then you need to find what's different about this and the other pages.  It looks fine to me.

Comment: some xhtml page do work..but don't know why some xhtml page are not working

Comment: Try moving `<script>myPara();</script>` right before the `</body>`